# PhoneRTC in Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, phonertc

I successfully manage to run the demo but in my case I want to make a video chat to make each one of clients to see each other but in the demo you can just see the caller or callee. How can I use phonertc just like the messenger app.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Group chat is not given as a feature in phoneRTC but, the base is available to create group calls. Please refer to their own [documentation](https://github.com/alongubkin/phonertc/wiki/Getting-Started) (the last paragraph)